# make a python GridDb client

Tags: python, client, griddb

When i try to make a python client appear this error:
$ make
g++ -fPIC -std=c++0x -g -O2 -c -o src/griddb_python.o -Iinclude -Isrc -I/usr/include/python3.8 src/griddb_python.cxx
src/griddb_python.cxx: In function ‘PyObject* _wrap_Store_multi_put(PyObject*, PyObject*)’:
src/griddb_python.cxx:12946:34: error: invalid conversion from ‘const char*’ to ‘char*’ [-fpermissive]
12946 |         arg4[i] = convertObjToStr(containerName);
|                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
|                                  |
|                                  const char*
make: *** [Makefile:48: src/griddb_python.o] Error 1

i tried to make it const char* but still have errors with conversions

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.